# QGIS 3 on Mac OS - Where is the configuration directory?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, mac, qgis-3

I've got a fresh clean install of QGIS 3 running on Mac OS and I can't find where the plugin directory should be.

I don't have a directory at `~/.qgis3`.

I've search my drive with `locate qgis` and `locate plugins | grep qgis` and can't see it anywhere.

I actually have two QGIS 3 installs, one using Homebrew and the other using Kyngchaos, and when I start either, they list the same installed plugins, so there must be a directory somewhere!

So, where is the QGIS 3 config directory on Mac OS hiding?

Edit: Nyall helped me find it! It's at `~/Library/Application\ Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/` (the default component is a named profile, which is a new feature).

Comment: Didn't watch mine and Nyall's talk at QGIS Aus conf hey Alex ;)

Comment: Clearly not! Rather foolish of me not to look in the place it's actually supposed to be!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Settings Menu, User Profiles, select "Open active profile folder". You'll be taken straight there.